# Induction and Recursion: $f(1)=2$ and $f(n)=f(n-1)+2n$ for $n>1$

Tags: induction, recursion

I have bad time with induction and recursion and I have an exam soon.

We have this:
$$f(1)=2$$
$$∀n>1:f(n)=f(n-1)+2n$$

We need to proof that is the solution of f(n)=f(n-1)+2n,f(1)=2 is:

(the solution need be prooven with induction)

$$f(n)=n(n+1)$$

### solution:

#### Base case:

#### n=1:

$$f(1)=2$$
$$f(1)=1(2)$$

#### We can assume that:

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+2n = f(n)n(n+1)$$

#### Inductive Step:

I don't know what to do next??

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's straightforward really, which makes me believe that there is something very important that you're missing. How would you start? **Edit:** You have a typo on the last equality.

Comment: It should be "We assume that $f(k)=k(k+1)$."  (It's less ambiguous to use a different symbol).  From here, we know $f(k+1)=f(k)+2(k+1)$ and $f(k)=k(k+1)$, which we combine and rearrange to give $f(k+1)=(k+1)(k+2)$, thereby completing the inductive step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+2n$$
And we need to prove:
$$f(n)=n(n+1)$$
Now let's check for $n=1$:
$$f(1)=1(1+1)=2$$
Now let's assume it's correct for n, i.e. that $f(n)=n(n+1)$, so we can use it.
$$f(n-1)+2n=n(n+1)$$
Now let's prove for $n+1$:
$$f(n+1-1)+2(n+1)=(n+1)(n+2)$$
$$f(n)+2n+2=(n+1)(n+2)$$
Now we can use the assumption, and substitute $f(n)$ with it's assumed value  $n(n+1)$:
$$n(n+1)+2n+2=(n+1)(n+2)$$
$$n^2+n+2n+2=n^2+3n+2$$
$$n^2+3n+2=n^2+3n+2$$
And that's correct.

Now by the Induction Axiom, we proved the theorem.

Answer (score 5):

In order to prove $$f(n)=n(n+1)$$ for all $n \geq 1$ by induction:

- *Base case*:  Show that $f(1)=1 \times (1+1)$.
- *Inductive step*:  We assume the inductive hypothesis that $f(k)=k(k+1)$ and use this to show $f(k+1)=(k+1)(k+2)$ using the identity $f(k+1)=f(k)+2(k+1)$.

Then we conclude, by induction, that $f(n)=n(n+1)$ holds for all $n \geq 1$.